# Xamarin Android Visual Studio 2022 - Need to change back arrow color (in top left corner) in my android application

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I need to change the back arrow color in my android application.
I tried a few solutions but none of them worked for me.

Comment: You tried by calling this method : NavigationPage.SetIconColor(BindableObject, Color) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
            <!-- Customize color of navigation drawer icon and back arrow -->
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/mytestcolor</item>
</style>
```

And add this style as theme to your toolbar in toolbar layout.xml using `app:theme` property,just as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

    app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" 

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And a usage example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
             
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Besides**, you can also use your own icon by using `app:navigationIcon` and set the title color by property `app:titleTextColor`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/my_purple"
    
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```